# Apache mod_ssl http to https

Tags: apache-httpd

I've installed OTRS 6 on CentOS7 to exlpore it's features and I struggle to make it available via `https`. It installs Apache, and I have installed the mod_ssl module, created a self-signed certificate and modified the `ssl.conf` file to point to the private key and the certificate file. When I access the web page via https://server/otrs/index.pl I get the self-signed certificate warning and I'm able to access it but I can still access it via `HTTP`. Few google searches later I'm still not able to prevent or re-direct all `HTTP` requests to `https`. I've found this article [Using an SSL certificate with OTRS](https://huntingbears.nl/2015/01/25/using-an-ssl-certificate-with-otrs/) and it says to put the following lines in the HTTP virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But the problem is that in my ssl.conf there is no section for HTTP virtual host, I can see only one for HTTPS `<VirtualHost_default_:443`

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thank you. Should I put it in the ssl.conf file under <VirtualHost_default_:443 ?

Comment: This should be in the `.htaccess` file and you should have a line `Redirect permanent / https://<your_site_name>/` in the `<VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost>` block in your site conf file

Comment: .htaccess - it's not there

Comment: Place it here `/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_otrs.conf` from docs I have seen, yours might be called differently

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to add anything else in the .httaccess file or just what you have wrote?

Comment: Please use the `.conf` file that comes with the installation

Comment: you mean the zzz_otrs.conf file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71667/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-adam86).

Comment: I got it working on my CentOS7 vm so ping me when you see this!

Comment: It's not working for me. I have added RedirectMatch http://otrs/otrs/index.pl https://otrs/otrs/index.pl it still opens http :/

Comment: It should be http://localhost/otrs/index.pl and https://localhost/otrs/index.pl

Comment: I changed it now and restarted Apache but still http is opening without redirection. Is it important where exactly I need to put this line like which line number ? I have added to line 26, is it ok ?

Comment: Please look at the code I pasted in the chat you will I posted my own otrs config file

Comment: it looks like yours but http is still not redirected :/ how do you access it via localhost?

Comment: Yes as it is in the config file

Comment: I'm unable to access via http://localhost/otrs/index.pl but it does not work with the hostaname as well i'm lost

Comment: I used localhost in my case so your has to be defferent!